# How to display a cv2 video inside a python GUI?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, opencv

I'm creating a GUI using Python/PyQt5 which should display a video along with other widgets in the same window. I've tried different approaches to this problem but stil can't seem to get it to work.

Approach 1: 
Adding the video in a pixmap using OpenCV/cv2 only shows the first frame of the video.

Approach 2: 
I have managed to get the video to play using cv2 however, it opens up in a new window.

Approach 3: 
I also tried using QVideoWidget, but a blank screen shows and the video does not play.

```
# only shows an image from the video, but in the correct place
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mov')
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            pix = QPixmap.fromImage(img)
            pix = pix.scaled(600, 400, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            self.ui.label_7.setPixmap(pix)

        # opens new window
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mov')

        while (cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            self.ui.frame = cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()

        # shows a blank screen 
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        videoWidget = self.ui.vid_widget
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile('video.mov')))
```

Any help on how to get the video play inside another widget/in the same window would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `while` loop, you need to convert `frame` into a `QPixmap` again, similar to what you did above, and then update `ui`:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mov')

while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
    pix = QPixmap.fromImage(img)
    pix = pix.scaled(600, 400, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
    self.ui.label_7.setPixmap(pix)    

    self.ui.frame = pix  # or img depending what `ui.frame` needs

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!