# Using Python play a video within a square frame in the same window. Video player should not be opened in an individual window

Tags: python, window, frame, opencv, qimage

My requirement is to create a window in which I have a square frame. And I need to play the video inside this square frame.

I think I can solve my requirement if I can correctly run the code here: [How to display a cv2 video inside a python GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076105/how-to-display-a-cv2-video-inside-a-python-gui).

As I am new to Python coding, I am facing some issues...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exp2.py", line 10, in <module>
    img = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
NameError: name 'QImage' is not defined
```

please help!

Comment: You are missing imports. In general it might be a good idea to learn the language you are trying to program in.

Answer (score 1):

You should import `QImage` at the beggining of the program.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to get each individual frame of a video, and insert that frame inside of the image:

frame.copyTo(img(cv2.Rect(x,y,frame.cols, frame.rows)))

This will put the `frame` inside of `img` starting at `x,y` ending at `frame.cols, frame.rows`